# Invalid Condition Key when trying to limit access to a sepific Lambda in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have this policy I'm trying to apply to my s3 bucket:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::integration",
            "arn:aws:s3:::integration/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "lambda:FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:ingestion-lambda"
                }
        }
    }]
 }
```

AWS keeps throwing the error "Policy has an invalid condition key" though. The docs seem to indicate these are the correct keys to use for specifying a lambda in a condition.

My intent is to block access to this s3 bucket except from the specified lambda function (I will add additional conditions to allow access from admin users, this snippet is just for brevity)

Comment: No, `lambda:FunctionArn` is not a valid condition key in bucket policy. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html

Comment: In general, it's best to avoid Deny policies, since they would even block access for your Admins to access the bucket. What are you _actually_ wanting to accomplish? Are you wanting to grant access to the bucket to an AWS Lambda function, but deny access to everything else? Feel free to edit your question to add more detail rather than answering via a comment.

Comment: The principle should be of type `AWS` with lambda execution role arn as its value instead of condition. But I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I tried to clarify my post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. Therefore, nobody will have access unless you have granted access via an IAM Policy.

It is quite dangerous to use `Deny` policies. A policy like one you have shown would prevent access to the bucket for Administrators, and would even remove your ability to modify the bucket policy! (You can use the Root account to restore access.)

Therefore, my recommendation would be:

- Do not put a bucket policy on the bucket
- Grant access to the AWS Lambda function via an IAM Role
- Do not grant access to IAM Users or other IAM Roles (it will remain private by default)

Comment: Thank you, I understand the dangers of deny, my example was just a snippet to get my question across. I intend to add additional conditions allowing select access beyond the single lambda - this bucket is intended to be very locked down and for reasons beyond the scope of this question, using a role on the lambda isn't an option

Comment: For "very locked down", I normally recommend creating the bucket in a separate AWS Account. That way, you don't need to worry about Admins having access to "all buckets". You can be very selective in what resources get access to the bucket, without playing with "Deny" policies. As you've seen, it isn't easy to write "negative" policies.

Comment: Suppose the question is flipped and I wanted to allow a specific lambda, could you help offer how to correct my snippet above to limit it to a specific lambda?

Comment: It's not a matter of "limiting". Rather, you would give that Lambda function an IAM Role that permits it to access the bucket. The important part, however, is making sure you aren't granting access to that bucket elsewhere (eg via a bucket policy, or via permissions on other IAM Users or IAM Roles). Everything is private by default, so it's a matter of being careful who/what gets permissions. That's why it's often a bad idea to grant all-access 'admin' type permissions. It's like handing out keys to your house -- rather than preventing everybody from entering, just don't hand out the keys!